# .concat() is not working with String.valueOf

Tags: java, concatenation

```
/**
 * Gets the initials of the name .
 * 
 * @return the initials of the name.
 */public String initials() 
{
   String result = name.substring(0, 1);
   for (int i = 0; i < name.length() - 1; i++)
   {
        if(name.charAt(i) == ' ')
        {
           result.concat(String.valueOf(name.charAt(i + 1)));
        }
    }
  return result;
 }
```

The tester is below which only returns 'J' after calling the initials method:

```
Name name = new Name("John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt");
System.out.println(name.initials());
System.out.println("Expected: JJJS");
```

When I write the code in this way, the following char after converted to String still cannot concat after the result, and only returns the first letter of the name.

Comment: Please, add appropriate tags to indicate what language are you using. Also, share enough code so that others can understand the problem you are facing.

Comment: You should normally use `+` to concatenate strings, not the string `concat(..)` method.

Answer (score 3):

[`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is an immutable class i.e. [`String#concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)) creates a new `String` which you need to assign back to result as shown below:

```
result = result.concat(String.valueOf(name.charAt(i + 1)));
```